# Composer-rest-server with passport-local strategy

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am not able to find a working solution to authenticate using local strategy in composer-rest-server. In fact only one working solution is using github. I tried setting up the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS as

```
export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "local": { 
    "provider": "local", 
    "module": "passport-local", 
    "usernameField": "username", 
    "passwordField": "password", 
    "authPath": "/auth/local", 
    "callbackURL":"/auth/local/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/", 
    "failureRedirect": "/", 
    "setAccessToken": true, 
    "callbackHTTPMethod": "post" 
   }
}'
```

but no luck. I am not even getting a login form for this. for localhost:3000/auth/local , I am getting 404. Looks like no one has tried local authentication strategy till now. I am new to nodejs programming. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Others may post a solution, but you may wish to refer to these links: [Where to put PassportJs local strategy in an express application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594949/where-to-put-passportjs-local-strategy-in-an-express-application) and https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-passport/issues/99 and [How to use passport-local to authenticate in composer rest server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216970/how-to-use-passport-local-to-authenticate-in-composer-rest-server)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing the callback function to default one in passport-configurator.js

Comment: Hi @Jay KM, can you explain where do you change the callback function?

Comment: Change it at line 556 of passport-configurator.js file. you need to set  self.app.post(authPath,defaultCallback); in if (authType == local) block

Comment: Where is this passport-configurator file?